# A normal code occurs java.lang.NullPointerException when it is run on another machine

Tags: java, apache-flink

I write a code to consume stream from Kafka and then sink it to MySQL.

The code runs normally on my IDE and can insert data into target table as expected.

However, when I submit the jar to Flink(deployed on the 192.168.95.2) web page, it throws `NullPointerException` on the `preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);` statement. The other codes on these part is:

```
private static PreparedStatement preparedStatement;
sql = "insert into kafka_ccu values(?,?)";
```

I am so confused...If there is any issue with connection or access, why the code can run normally on my IDE? Any help is appreciated.

The full exception is:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at DemoKafka2Mysql$2.invoke(DemoKafka2Mysql.java:92)
    at DemoKafka2Mysql$2.invoke(DemoKafka2Mysql.java:72)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSink.processElement(StreamSink.java:56)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.pushToOperator(OperatorChain.java:641)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.collect(OperatorChain.java:616)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.collect(OperatorChain.java:596)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator$CountingOutput.collect(AbstractStreamOperator.java:730)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator$CountingOutput.collect(AbstractStreamOperator.java:708)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamMap.processElement(StreamMap.java:41)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.pushToOperator(OperatorChain.java:641)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.collect(OperatorChain.java:616)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.collect(OperatorChain.java:596)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$BroadcastingOutputCollector.collect(OperatorChain.java:711)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$BroadcastingOutputCollector.collect(OperatorChain.java:664)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator$CountingOutput.collect(AbstractStreamOperator.java:730)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator$CountingOutput.collect(AbstractStreamOperator.java:708)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSourceContexts$NonTimestampContext.collect(StreamSourceContexts.java:104)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSourceContexts$NonTimestampContext.collectWithTimestamp(StreamSourceContexts.java:111)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.internals.AbstractFetcher.emitRecordWithTimestamp(AbstractFetcher.java:398)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.internal.KafkaFetcher.emitRecord(KafkaFetcher.java:185)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.internal.KafkaFetcher.runFetchLoop(KafkaFetcher.java:150)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumerBase.run(FlinkKafkaConsumerBase.java:715)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSource.run(StreamSource.java:100)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSource.run(StreamSource.java:63)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.SourceStreamTask$LegacySourceFunctionThread.run(SourceStreamTask.java:196)
```

My codes (stream source is not Kinesis but same issue...):

```
public class DemoKinesis2Mysql {

private static  Connection connection;
private static PreparedStatement preparedStatement;
private static String sql = "";
private static String username;
private static String password;
private static String drivername;
private static String dburl;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    StreamExecutionEnvironment see = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
    see.setParallelism(1);
    getConn(); 

    Properties consumerConfig = new Properties();
    consumerConfig.put(AWSConfigConstants.AWS_REGION, "aaa");
    consumerConfig.put(AWSConfigConstants.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, "ddd");
    consumerConfig.put(AWSConfigConstants.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, "xxx");
    consumerConfig.put(ConsumerConfigConstants.STREAM_INITIAL_POSITION, "LATEST");

    DataStream<String> kinesis = see.addSource(new FlinkKinesisConsumer<>(
            "target_stream",
            new SimpleStringSchema(),
            consumerConfig));

    kinesis.print();

    DataStream<JSONObject> mapStream = kinesis.map(new MapFunction<String, JSONObject>() {
        public JSONObject map(String s) throws Exception {
            JSONObject jsonObject = JSON.parseObject(s);
            return jsonObject;
        }
    }).filter(new FilterFunction<JSONObject>() {
        public boolean filter(JSONObject jsonObject) throws Exception {
            if (jsonObject.containsKey("Body")) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });


    mapStream.addSink(new RichSinkFunction<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void open(Configuration parameters) throws Exception {
            super.open(parameters);
        }

        @Override
        public void close() throws Exception {
            if (preparedStatement != null) {
                preparedStatement.close();
            }
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.close();
            }
        }


        public void invoke(JSONObject value, Context context) throws Exception  {
            JSONArray arr = JSON.parseObject(value.getString("Body")).getJSONArray("metrics");
            log.info("json array:" + arr);
            for (int i=0;i<arr.size();i++) {
                JSONObject o = arr.getJSONObject(i);
                preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
                String k = "";
                if (o.containsKey("key")) {
                    k = o.getString("key");
                }
                String d = o.getJSONObject("properties").getString("datetime");
                if (k.equals("ccu")) {
                    String t = o.getJSONObject("properties").getString("ccu");
                    preparedStatement.setObject(1, t);
                    preparedStatement.setObject(2, d);
                    preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
                    }
                }
            }

    });
    see.execute();
}

private static void getConn() throws SQLException {
    username = "user";
    password = "123456";
    drivername = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    dburl = "jdbc:mysql://192.168.95.2:3306/test?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&useSSL=false&autoReconnect=true";
    sql = "insert into tmp_stream_kinesis_ccu (ccu,data_time) values(?,?)";
    try {
        Class.forName(drivername);
    }catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(dburl, username, password);
}
```

}

Comment: Is your database connection successful from your deployment server?

Comment: @AmitB10 Thanks for your reply. I tried the connection str `mysql -h192.168.95.2 -uroot -p'123456'` on the Flink deployment server and it successfully connects to mysql. These are the info I wrote in the code.

Comment: Can you log your connection object? It will be null for sure..

Comment: @AmitB10 Thanks for your help! I tried to print the connection object and both my IDE and flink log show `connection object is: com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@25268233`

Comment: Can you please post the code as well?

Comment: Hi @HaseebAsif Thanks for your help~ I just post my code as well. I change the stream source from `Kafka` to `Kinesis`, but still suffering the same issue: it is running on my IDE but when submitted to Flink, same exception...

Comment: It seems getconnection is returning null probably due to connection issues . the next thing I would do to verify that throw an exception as when we get null connection in getConn method
Other thing I would try localhost in the dburl instead of the machine IP.

Comment: Have you verify whether the version whatever you mention in pom.xml for mysql driver is supported by flink or not.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```java
if (connection == null || connection.isClosed()) return;
PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use side effects in your user code, make sure you initialize everything in your user functions. Here is a rough sketch.

```
public class MyMap extends RichMapFunction {
    public void open() {
        connection = ...;
        statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
    }
    public void close() {
        statement.close();
        connection.close();
    }
    ...
}
```